# how to give label custom font family name without its size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my app i have created one custom class for Label.Now i want to give only font family name without specifying the size.For that i wrote following code:

```
      lbl.font=[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold"];
```

But it gives warning like Incompatible pointer type assigning to UIFont from NSArray.

Please guide me or suggest me the way to do this.

Comment: Have u first allocated the label?

Comment: lbl1 = [[uilabel alloc]init];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot specify the `font family` alone. You need to specify the `size` too.

**Refer to:**

[UIFont Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

**Here you need to use:**

`+ (UIFont *)fontWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)fontSize` method

**Code:**

```
lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold" size:14.0f];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

UIFont's `fontNamesForFamilyNames:` method returns an NSArray of NSStrings, not a UIFont. I think you what you want is `fontWithName:size:`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above code is that `[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"familyName"]` returns an array of acceptable font names for the `familyName`, not a single UIFont or even an array of UIFonts.

Is there any reason you don't want to specify the size? All the size does is scale the font by the specified size, so a size of 1.0 keeps the font at it's normal size. In this case just do `lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontName" size:1.0]`